# Connect 2 computers to 1 printer

Tags: router, printer, modem, multiple-computers

What the title says.
So what i have:

- 1 modem
- 1 router (Linksys E1200)
- 1 printer (hp deskjet ink advantage 3835)
- 1 (A)PC with windows xp on it (don't ask why)
- 1 (B)PC with windows 10

---

### How these parts are connected:

-on PC(A) we have the modem with an ethernet cable and the printer with a usb cable so computer (A) can recognize the printer.

-then from the modem another ethernet cable goes to the router, where the router works as an extension for computer (B) because another ethernet cable is connected from the router to computer (B).

---

Just to clarify, computer (A) sees printer because it's connected with a usb cable but not computer (B) which is only connected to the router.

How do I make computer (B) see the printer?

Comment: You don't.  You remove the Windows XP device from the network as its foolhardy to it network enabled, as it can be used as an inflection point to compromise the rest of your network.    As you will no doubt not listen to my perl of wisdom, you would set up network sharing and then printer sharing on the Windows XP machine - which will make it a "Network Printer" to the Windows 10 system.  That you don't know this and still run XP means you should not be doing this.

Comment: Thank you for the instruction, i will try and do this and get back to you.

Comment: I really wish you wouldn't !